# JS - how to end a db connection with chained promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mariadb

I declare my DB functions in one file and want them to return a promise so I can re-use them elsewhere. Question is how to end the connection? I know I could probably call `conn.end()` in every place I call my DB function but could I not do it in the DB function itself?

Caller...

```
function scanBoard(qrCode) {
    getBoard(qrCode)
    .then(b => {
        board = b;
    });
}
```

DB function (note, code wont run as it contains all the things I've tried)

```
function getBoard(qrcode) {

    return db.createConnection(dbConfig)
    .then(conn => {
        let rows = conn.query("SELECT * FROM boards WHERE id = ?", [qrcode])
        .then(() => { conn.end() }); // Can't call it here cus it ends conn before rows is set

        conn.end(); // Can't call it here cus rows is still pending

        if (rows.length >= 1)
            return rows[0];

        return null;
    })
    .finally({
        conn.end(); // Can't call it here cus it gets called before the 'then' block in the caller
    });


}
```

Comment: `let rows = conn.query(`  rows will never be set here..  `cus it ends conn before rows is set`  No that's were rows will be, it's just that it will get passed into the params.

Comment: IOW: `.then((rows) => { /* rows is here*/ conn.end() });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest closing the connection after each db method call. it is very less efficient, instead you could use connection pool. see here for more details

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections

And when all the work is done you can close the connections in pool. See this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#closing-all-the-connections-in-a-pool

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've made this the answer as I've gone for the pool solution in the end.

Answer (score 1):

`conn.query` is async, therefor `then` will complete and `finally` will be triggered before the query has yielded any results, even if it only takes a couple ms. It does not matter that you're resolving the promise, the enclosing promise will fulfill, or rather the chained `then` will fulfill.

```
async function getBoard(qrcode) {
  const conn = await db.createConnection(dbConfig);

  try {
    return await conn.query("SELECT * FROM boards WHERE id = ?", [qrcode]);
  } finally {
    conn.end();
  }
}
```

Just as a tip - If this application is running constantly, you can just connect to the db once and reuse the connection, then the need to open and close the connection for every query is eliminated.

Comment: You have this all mixed up, your using `async / await`, and then don't use it, and then use a Promise constructor when it's not needed..

Comment: No, problem.  Your nearly there, if your going to use `async/await` tad more to do.  `async function getBoard(qrcode) { const con = await db.createConnection(dbConfig); const rows = await.....` etc.   And of course the normal  javascript `try finally` to ensure `con.end()`

Comment: That's even better, :)  Personally I would take out the -> `catch { return null;`  leave the exception to propagate, otherwise the calleee will have to do a 'null' check, and worse still will not know why they was an error.

Comment: ps.  Also I can understand why you used a `let` for scoping reasons.  But you don't require it,  you could do -> `const conn = await db.create...`, and place the try after this line, currently makes no sense having before anyway, IOW: can't do a `conn.end` if a conn was never returned.

Comment: Right, weird I overlooked that. You actually helped me tremendously with your comments today, so thanks for that. I'll tackle these issues more efficiently from now on I'm sure!

Answer (score -1):

I think that here the best solution is following the best practices...
To solve your problem i think is better to sorround the `conn.end();` in the `finally` part of the promise chain with an if so it gets triggered only if the query went well or if there is no requests pending. I'll do it like so:

```
.finally({
      if(conn){
          conn.end();
      }
 });
```

Obviously you have to remove the `conn.end();` code line from any other part of your source code. I would even think about checking for other errors with more `catch()`.

hope it helped it me up with any question you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
  async function scanBoard(qrCode)
 {

      let board = await getBoard(qrCode);
  }
  catch (e)
  {
      throw e;
  }

 }

async function getBoard(qrcode)
      {

                let dbConn = await  db.createConnection(dbConfig);
                let rows = await dbConn.query("SELECT * FROM boards WHERE id = ?", [qrcode]);
                if (rows.length >= 1)

                // If you need to re-use connection, create a connection instance and re-use.Do not close here

                return rows[0];            
        }
```

Comment: this doesnt use promises

Comment: A couple of things -> `catch (e)  {  throw e;` does nothing.    `if(dbConn)` will always be true.

Comment: @TedTrippin  Yes, it does.

Comment: @Keith while querying or creating connection error occurs we need to catch and throw the error. It has nothing to do with `if(dbConn)`. You can get rid of that condition. It is just safeguarding object before closing
So i think it is valid

Comment: No, you don't have to throw..  `catch(e) { throw e` is a null op.

Comment: If you don't throw from here, the called wont get the exception returned. This is why try catch is for.We need to make errors get caught and no unhandled rejection happens

Comment: @Keith does it? I'm relatively new to this stuff. Shouldnt there be a `then` somewhere if promises are in use? I realise `query` returns a promise but the resultant promise is never accessed, right?

Comment: @Sohan  No, the the `called` will get the exception.

Comment: @TedTrippin  `async / await` just sits on top of Promises..  It's basically syntax sugar for using `then` ables..

Comment: @Sohan  Why do I need to check that out?  Believe me, doing `cache(e) { throw e; }` does absolutely nothing, apart from making your code look ugly and wasting some CPU cycles...

Comment: My understand is using try/catch does better error handling and looks better. You can even throw your custom errors. That is what it is for

Comment: @Sohan  I know how exceptions work.. If you do something with the exception, then it makes sense.  eg, log to to some database, throw a different exception. etc.  But just re-throwing the same exception gains you nothing..  It won't harm, so don't worry if you have lots of code with it in, but for future code cleanup, might make sense to get rid.

Comment: okay, my point above was to make sure code execute. I will update answer